# What is the difference between router and route in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

What is the difference between router and route in emberjs? I wanted an implementable explanation if possible

Comment: have you asked difference between `router` and `route` or  `resource` and `route`  ?

Comment: The difference is as described in the quite comprehensive Ember documentation on the topic. Google for "ember router" and "ember route".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The practical difference between these two is that resource may contain other routes, whereas route cannot. Additionally, this.resource automatically creates an index route when it sees you have sub-routes.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('records', function() {
    // this.route('index') is created automatically in here
    this.route('new');
  });

  this.route('about');
});
```

While you could always use this.resource and have things work correctly, this.route explicitly creates router leaf states and therefore will lead to a more precise and efficient graph of states for your app.

Comment: I think the questions was what is difference between `route` and `router` not difference between `routes` and `resources`

Comment: If you're going to answer this question (which was not the one which was asked), you could point out that resources are being deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

**Router** - ember application will have one Router, it manages transitions between routes and it contains map of all routes. You specify map of routes like so:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
    this.route('comments', { resetNamespace: true }, function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

from which *Router* is able to identify structure of routes and their accepting params. It activates corresponding *Route* when you navigate to particular path/url in browser [ember router docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html)

**Route** - for each *path/route* you will have Route object, when you change path/url in browser corresponding Route gets activated for that path and set up everything (controller, template) which relate to that route (that has same name usually).
 [ember route docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html)

[read more](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/concepts/core-concepts/)